# Approximation of adapted continuous random function by adapted polynomials

Tags: stochastic-processes

Given filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. Let $f(t,x)$ is adapted with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ continuous in $t$ and $x$ function. Question: Is there sequence of adapted functions  $f_n(t,x)$ such that  $f_n(t,x)$  is polynomial in $x$ and $f_n(t,x)$ converges to $f(t,x)$ uniformly on each compact $x \in[a,b]$? It seems the answer is yes, but how to prove it?
This statement is used in the proof of Ito formula, when $f(t,x)$ if itself random adapted function.